# Combine SIM contacts to single contact back in phone

Tags: contacts, 4.1-jelly-bean, people-app

I have researched on the net for this and have come accross useful apps like Merge+, Duplicate contacts, etc.

But they don't exhibit the feature that i am looking for..

When we copy contacts from phone to SIM, if a contact has multiple numbers associated, each of these numbers gets stored as a separate contact. For example, contact "abc" with numbers num1 and num2 will get stored as two separate contacts abc->num1 and abc1->num2.

I want to merge these contacts back to single contact when imported to phone. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: This may just have to be a slow, manual process. I don't know of any other way.

Comment: Not sure if this is exactly what you mean (hence being a comment), but if you log into Gmail and go to your contacts, there is a merge tool.

Comment: This is not about google contacts but any contacts inside phone. I don't want my phone number contacts on the net!